# Threading with simple client/serverTCP connection

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having issues with implementing simple TCP client-server connection in Java, android studio. Networking operations can't run on mainUI thread, asynctask is deprecated, so I'm trying to use Threading. I created client socket in MainActivity and then want it to connect to the server:

```
client= new ClientTCP();
Log.d("MSG", "Trying to start...");
client.startConnection("xxxxxxxxxxx",8888);
```

It works well. Now I would like to do more operations such as *send a message* but I can't just create another Thread for it. At the current state, MainActivity doesn't see **client** socket as initialized becaused of the threading in Connect() function. It's only working in that particular thread.
What should I do now to make both the Connect and sendMsg (and possibly other networking functions) work on the same thread so they are all initialized and seen in ActivityMain? Right now, this:

```
client.sendMessage("Im gonna crash.");
```

crashes the app.

```
public class Client
{
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;

            public void Connect(String ip, int port)
            {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
                            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                            Log.d("MSG", "Started Connection!");

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }).start();
            }


            public void sendMessage (String msg){
               new Thread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(clientSocket.isConnected()) {
                        out.println(msg+"\n");
                }
             }
          }).start();
        }

            public void stopConnection() {
                try {
                    out.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should send the message in the run() of a runnable() of a new thread.

Comment: If you all wanna do in one thread then do connect, send, receive, disconnect in the run() of a runnable() of one thread.

Comment: `client.sendMessage("Im.....` will crash your app with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Why didn't you tell us?

Comment: @blackapps hi, could you please tell me if that would be the *correct* way? I just encapsulated these functions into new thread(new Runnable())

Comment: I see nothing..